# Why does Titan's (relatively) rapid migration away from Saturn cause the planet to wobble faster, and eventually (maybe) tip onto its side?

Tags: gravity, general-relativity, natural-satellites, saturn, theories

Over the past year and a half, multiple articles in the popular press have come out talking about how unexpectedly rapidly Titan is moving away from Saturn, and how this is causing Saturn to wobble more, not less, on its axis.  It is even said that this may cause Saturn to flip entirely onto its side!

Titan is much, much smaller compared to Saturn than our Moon is to Earth, so....

Why is this happening?  And since our Moon is migrating away from us, albeit at roughly half the rate, are we doomed to more wobbliness and a flip onto our side?

Comment: You might want to read https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2021/03/aa39891-20.pdf and https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-020-01284-x for more information. I’m not sure, though, if your answer is in there…